# Strange Session behaviour

Tags: cakephp, session-cookies

Some of our visitors told us that loggin in into our site isnt possible. After a long research we find out that it seems that there may be problems with the sessions. It seems, they get lost or are not even set.

Is that a cake related problem or what can we do to avoid such bad behaviour of our site? We allready added the following session settings in the core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session', array('defaults' => 'php'));
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Session.ini', array('session.cookie_secure' => false,'session.referer_check' => false));
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Session.cookie_secure', false);
Configure::write('Session.referer_check', false);
Configure::write('Session.defaults', 'php');
Configure::write('Session.cookieTimeout', 0);
```

best
stefan

Comment: Do you know which browsers this is a problem for?

Comment: Have you specified a custom session-name? I once had a problem with a invalid session name (containing dashes or underscores) that was refused by some browsers.

Comment: theJeztah: No, I have the standard name, I think its CAKEPHP

Comment: Nick: mostly ie and chrome